# No such column error in sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table with:

```
 create table student(name text, id integer,year text,section text,
                      subject text, branch text, date text, attendance integer);
```

And when I retrieve rows using where clause it gives an error saying that there is no such column apple (actually apple is value of section column)

```
public long insertRow(String name, int id, String year, String section,
                      String subject, String branch, String date, int att) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ROLLNO, id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_YEAR, year);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SECTION, section);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUBJECT, subject);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BRANCH, branch);  
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ATTENDANCE,att);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

This is the function to retrieve all rows:

```
public Cursor getAllRows(String year, String section, String branch,
                           String subject, String date) {    

    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROLLNO,KEY_ATTENDANCE}, 
                    KEY_YEAR + "=" + year +
                    " AND "+ KEY_SECTION + "=" + section +
                    " AND "+ KEY_BRANCH + "=" + branch + 
                    " AND "+ KEY_SUBJECT + "=" + subject + 
                    " AND "+ KEY_DATE + "=" + date,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app on your test device, cleaning the project, recompiling and reuploading?

Comment: you should use the constants when creating the database -- you might just have a typo and you're not seeing it

Comment: @pouzzler how to delete app on my test device??

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't included KEY_SECTION column in your query, try

```
new String[] { KEY_ROLLNO,KEY_ATTENDANCE, KEY_SECTION }
```

in your `query()` or simply `null`

It seems you will need other columns as well because they are used by your WHERE clause.

Comment: @animuson can u help to slove this

Comment: I meant substitute 2nd argument in your query() with null and see if it helps

Comment: thanks for ur info...i have one more doubt...can we compare text data in a table with string datatype....in the above code section is string and the values in table are text....

Comment: From  a current position of a Cursor c you retrieve a value of a text field FLD_MYTEXT like this: 
String txtFromDb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FLD_MYTEXT))